# Is there a guide or checklist for doing code reviews?

Tags: issue-tracking

I've searched a little bit on the net to find a good guide on submitting and reviewing code reviews for my team.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Take your time to conduct the review.
- The purpose of review is to carefully understand and analyze design and code. - Spend up to half the time on a review that you did writing the code or planning the design originally.
- Let the reviewers drive the review.
- The reviewers and their comments must drive a review. If developers are allowed to lead reviews of their own work, other reviewers might miss problems.
- Read the code or design document before the review meeting.
- Code sent for review is not sender.
- You’ll always find somebody who knows better.
- Challenge ideas but accept defeat gracefully.
- Treat each other respectfully!!!
- Track all issues found during code reviews.

I've a blog post about code reviews: [A guide for Code Reviews](http://www.yusufaytas.com/a-guide-for-code-reviews/). Please read it.

Comment: This answer is confusing...

Comment: "Code written is not sender"? What?

Comment: So ultimately, this answer is just a link to your blog, which is basically what the question is asking for... and why it's receiving close votes...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio, it has a good tool for code reviews. Very helpful for submitting review. You can assign reviewers from Team Foundation Server users.

The practice we are using: every developer has a review partner.

Code standards is one of the important thing in reviews.

Code analysis tools also decrease review efforts such as FxCop and StyleCop.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions.